# Docker - nodemon gets bugging errors

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, docker-machine, docker-registry

[Docker Nodemon Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hleaf.png)

Hi, every one. Can you please helping me to fix this probelm. I alerady follow the documentations which i get from Docker’s documentations. I get it from https://docs.docker.com/get-started/07_multi_container/ . That link that i already follow, it doesn’t work anything, then shows those errors. I also follow the steps one by one, but that plobelm comes to 7th step.

```
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:998
  throw err;
  ^
Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\nigel\Documents\Tutorial Nigel\Docker\app\index.js'
at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:995:15)
at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:841:27)
at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}

Node.js v18.12.1
```

I want to run the nodemon command in Windows docker, so i can see the Docker's processes

Comment: Can you [edit] the question to include a [mcve]?  A Docker container runs in an isolated environment (and possibly inside a hidden Linux VM as well) and the normal Docker design is that it can't access files on your host; would using Node directly, without Docker, be a simpler setup?